# R With an ifelse statement, how do I pull a value from another column when the condition is true?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

There is probably a simple solution for this but I've been struggling all night to get this and I can't find the right search terms to find an answer, so I appreciate any help.

Essentially, I am filling in a new dataframe by looking for the name of the rows in a different dataframe2, and if that name is in dataframe2 then I want to pull the value in the second column of datagrame2...and if it is not, then I want to add a zero.

Here is the code I have .. but this is randomly pulling values if the name is in dataframe2.

```
UTR3s.totes.df <- UTR3s.df
for (i in 1:317) {
  targets.df <- subset(TC_merge,V14==consmiRNAs[i])[,c(18,5)]
  targets <- intersect(targets.df$ENSEMBL, UTR3s$Gene)
  targets.df <- subset(targets.df, targets.df$ENSEMBL %in% targets)
  sitenumber = data.frame(Gene = UTR3s$Gene)
  UTR3s.totes.df[, paste("target",i,sep="")] <- ifelse(sitenumber$Gene %in% 
targets.df$ENSEMBL, targets.df$V5, "0")
}
```

Everything is working except for the last line ... pulling the corresponding value from the dataframe2 (targets.df)

**Reproducible Example added:**

```
U.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"))
targets.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name3","name5"),value=c(2,1,3))
U.df[, paste("target",i,sep="")] <- ifelse(U.df$name %in% targets.df$name, 
targets.df$value, "0")
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible example? Also did you have a look at `match()`?

Comment: Okay here is an example: 

    `U.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"))
    targets.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name3","name5"),value=c(2,1,3))  
    U.df[, paste("target",i,sep="")] <- ifelse(U.df$name %in% targets.df$name, targets.df$value, "0")`

You can see the right values don't go to the right names. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @ANG `match()` is giving me row numbers not the values in my second column???

Comment: I can really use any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: You only want to use an `ifelse()` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options you can try:

```
## data
U.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"))
targets.df <- data.frame(name=c("name1","name3","name5"),value=c(2,1,3))

## option 1 (based on merging the data frames)
library(dplyr)
U.df2 <- left_join(U.df, targets.df, by = "name")
U.df2$value[is.na(U.df2$value)] <- 0 # set NA values to 0
U.df2 # output
   name value
1 name1     2
2 name2     0
3 name3     1
4 name4     0
5 name5     3

## option 2 (if you only want an ifelse statement)
U.df$value <- ifelse(U.df$name %in% targets.df$name,
                     targets.df$value[match(U.df$name, targets.df$name)],
                     0)
U.df # output
   name value
1 name1     2
2 name2     0
3 name3     1
4 name4     0
5 name5     3
```